# Cross-thread operation not valid while listening to a COM port

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, multithreading, exception

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Getting Cross-thread operation not valid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1523878/getting-cross-thread-operation-not-valid)
>   [Cross-thread operation not valid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5037470/cross-thread-operation-not-valid)

I am trying to listen to COM port so that I create new handler for SerialPort.DataReceived event. The logic is simple - I write something to TextBox1, press Button1 and my text should show it self in Label1. But my application don't want to run, becouse it throws 'Cross thread operation not valid' error. 
I did some searching and found Invoke object - how can I use it in my example? Why do I need to include Invoke logic?

```
namespace WindowsApplication1
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    SerialPort sp = new SerialPort();

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        sp.DataReceived += MyDataReceivedHandler;
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void MyDataReceivedHandler(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            //sp.PortName = "COM3";
            //sp.Open();
            Label1.Text = sp.ReadLine();
        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
            RichTextBox1.Text = exception.Message + "\n\n" + exception.Data;
        }
        finally
        {
            sp.Close();
        }
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            sp.PortName = "COM3";
            sp.Open();
            sp.WriteLine(TextBox1.Text);
        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
            RichTextBox1.Text = exception.Message + "\n\n" + exception.Data;
        }
        finally
        {
            sp.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: @ Peter: COM port here is the RS232 serial interface. Despite USB and all there are still a number of devices (e.g. GPS, Medical) that use the serial port for PC communication.

Comment: @_simon_: Just curious: what is the COM port used for in this particular application?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

My guess is that `MyDataReceivedHandler` is running on a different thread than the GUI. In order to fix that, you need to invoke the `Text` setters on the correct thread. This is a sample of doing so:

```
public void SetControlText(Control control, string text)
{
    if (this.InvokeRequired)
    {
        this.Invoke(new Action<Control,string>(SetControlText), new object[] { control, text });
    }
    else
    {
        control.Text = text;
    }
}

private void MyDataReceivedHandler(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        //sp.PortName = "COM3";
        //sp.Open();
        SetControlText(Label1, sp.ReadLine());
    }
    catch (Exception exception)
    {
        SetControlText(RichTextBox1, exception.Message + "\n\n" + exception.Data);
    }
    finally
    {
        sp.Close();
    }
}
```

If you are using .NET Framework 2.0, the above `Action<T1, T2>` delegate is not available, so you will have to define your own one:

```
private delegate void SetControlTextHandler(Control control, string text);

public void SetControlText(Control control, string text)
{
    if (this.InvokeRequired)
    {
        this.Invoke(new SetControlTextHandler(SetControlText), new object[] { control, text });
    }
    else
    {
        control.Text = text;
    }
}
```

The `SetControlText` method can be made shorter (and even static) like this (this works in both 2.0 and 3.5):

```
public static void SetControlText(Control control, string text)
{
    ´control.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate { control.Text = text; });
}
```

Then you don't need to do the check of `InvokeRequired` each time, but you will on the other hand wrap the call in a delegate even if it is not needed. I think that in a GUI method like this any performance difference between those two is neglectible so I tend to use the shorter form, simply because it is less code to write.

Comment: It seems, that this works only in 3.5. I use Visual studio 2005, now I installed 3.5 SP1. Where in Visual studio 2005 can I set which .NET framework I am using?

Comment: @_simon_: I have updated the answer with 2.0 compatible versions

Comment: Note: If the operation performed in the delegate is long running, it can still block the UI as the invoke will just cause the UI thread to process the operation. Using BeginInvoke on all controls that implement it will perform the operation asynchronously, without blocking.

Comment: +1 and should you not call the invoke/begininvoke on the control, and not on 'this' (the form)?

Answer (score 1):

You can also do the following whenever accessing a UI control from a different thread than the one it was created on:

(.NET 3.5)

```
myControl.BeginInvoke(new MethodInvoker( () => myControl.whatever = whatever; ));
```

or
(.NET 2.0)

```
myControl.BeginInvoke(new MethodInvoker( delegate { myControl.whatever = whatever; ));
```

edit> Sometimes using Invoke for a long running operation can/will still hang the ui, using BeginInvoke obviously performs that operation asynchronously, and the ui will not hang.