# Getting Cross-thread operation not valid

Tags: c#, winforms, multithreading, exception

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Cross-thread operation not valid: Control accessed from a thread other than the thread it was created on](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/142003/cross-thread-operation-not-valid-control-accessed-from-a-thread-other-than-the)

```
public void CheckUnusedTabs(string strTabToRemove)
{ 
    TabPage tp = TaskBarRef.tabControl1.TabPages[strTabToRemove];
    tp.Controls.Remove(this);
    TaskBarRef.tabControl1.TabPages.Remove(tp);
}
```

I am trying to close a tab in the tabcontrol of windows application using the above code and i encountered the error:

> Cross-thread operation not valid.

How to solve this ?

Comment: even a search on "cross thread" in SO gives lots of results...

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You can only make changes to WinForm controls from the master thread. You need to check whether InvokeRequired is true on the control and then Invoke the method as needed.

You can do something like this to make it work:

```
public void CheckUnusedTabs(string strTabToRemove)
{ 
    if (TaskBarRef.tabControl1.InvokeRequired)
    {
        TaskBarRef.tabControl1.Invoke(new Action<string>(CheckUnusedTabs), strTabToRemove);
        return;
    }      

    TabPage tp = TaskBarRef.tabControl1.TabPages[strTabToRemove];
    tp.Controls.Remove(this);
    TaskBarRef.tabControl1.TabPages.Remove(tp);
}
```

Comment: FYI, your clear update of the original code was the only way I was able to figure out how to properly implement this in mine.  Thanks.

Answer (score 20):

call using invoke, because you're accessing the GUI thread using another thread

```
 this.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate() {CheckUnusedTabs(""); });
```

Comment: This worked for me with a similar case: updating GUI from external event.

Answer (score 5):

When using threads and UI controls, in winforms, you need to use [InvokeRequired](http://bytes.com/topic/c-sharp/answers/638367-threads-invokerequired-form-controls) to make changes to the controls.

EDIT.

added an example.

Form, with button and label.

try

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Thread thread = new Thread(UpdateProcess);
            thread.Start();
        }

        private void SetLabelText(string val)
        {
            label1.Text = val;
        }
        delegate void m_SetLabel(string val);

        private void UpdateProcess()
        {
            int i = 0;

            while (true)
            {
                if (label1.InvokeRequired)
                {
                    m_SetLabel setLabel = SetLabelText;
                    Invoke(setLabel, i.ToString());
                }
                else
                    label1.Text = i.ToString();
                i++;
                Thread.Sleep(500);
            }
        }
```

Comment: @astander, can u tell me how ?

Comment: @astander i tried adding ...

if(TaskBarRef.tabControl1.incokerequired)

Comment: check the answer, added an example.

Answer (score 1):

Cross thread not valid exception is due to the UI controls being accessed from other threads than main thread.see this 
http://helpprogramming.blogspot.com/2011/10/invalid-cross-thread-operation.html

Answer (score -3):

Set the following variable:

```
CheckIllegalCrossThreadValidation = false
```

Comment: CheckIllegalCrossThreadValidation is a safety check to prevent some versions of Windows from crashing when you try to do cross-thread UI updates. It's madness to turn it off.

Comment: For some reason Microsoft has added that option.