# Setting text boxes thread issues

Tags: c#, winforms, multithreading, textbox

I'm pretty new at C# so forgive me if this is a bit of a silly question.
Anyway I'm writing a little chat application that so far seems to be going well, I've run into a problem that I seem to have fixed but I'm hoping to work out why I need to do it this way.

When I receive a message I want to update a text box so I use:

```
txtConnectedID.Text = "test";
```

But I receive this error:

```
System.InvalidOperationException was unhandled by user code
  Message=Cross-thread operation not valid: Control 'txtConnectedID' accessed from a thread other than the thread it was created on.
```

Now, I think this has something to do with stopping the method running twice and not updating properly? I'm not 100% on this. So now I have a delegate for a method that accepts a string and I call:

```
private delegate void stringDelegate(string s);

BeginInvoke(new stringDelegate(writeToIPBox), new object[] { e.ConnectedIP.ToString() });

private void writeToIPBox(string newIP)
        {
            txtConnectedID.Text = newIP;
        }
```

I'm not sure why I'm doing this, how it's any different. I'm not really happy to just do it this way without knowing why.

Thanks in advance

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1523878/cross-thread-operation-not-valid-in-c

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should only attempt to update controls from the thread on which they were created.  There are good reasons for this as it is easy to hit a race condition.  These controls are not thread safe and this is the runtime helping you out a bit.

Instead, as you have figured out, you need to update it on the UI thread, which is what `BeginInvoke` is doing; calling the delegate asynchronously on the UI thread.

Answer (score 0):

All controls are owned by the UI thread (of which there is only one), and trying to access them from another thread results in this Exception.

`BeginInvoke` calls the specified delegate on the UI thread, which is why it works. You can also check if you are on the UI thread by checking `txtConnectedID.InvokeRequired`.

Answer (score 0):

It took a new minutes of determined googling but I eventually found an "authorative" reference:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.invokerequired%28v=vs.90%29.aspx

The short answer (to quote from that page) is: **Controls in Windows Forms are bound to a specific thread and are not thread safe.**

This article also aludes to how this can be handled "internally"... if `control.InvokeRequired` (i.e. we've been called from another thread) handle the invocation internally... rather than spreading delegates throughout your code.

Personally I'd never really questioned WHY a delegate was required, I just did it. Good question.

Cheers. Keith.

Answer (score 0):

```
private static void SetText(TextBox tb, string text)
{
    if (tb.InvokeRequired)
    {
        var stDelegate = new StDelegate(SetText);
        tb.Invoke(stDelegate, new object[] { tb, text });
    }
    else
    {
        tb.Text = text;
    }
}
```