# "Cross thread operation not valid" .. while reading data on Serial Port

Tags: c#, winforms, serial-port, multithreading

In a windows form application, on main form load, i have set a serial port and started reading it. The purpose is, as and when I receive some data on the serial port, I want to open another form related to the data.

So i use the DataReceived Event Handler of the serial port.

```
  void serialPort1_DataReceived(object sender, System.IO.Ports.SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
        {

            string str = this.serialPort1.ReadLine();


                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(str))
                {


                    Main.Instance.customerData = new CustomerData(str);
                    Main.Instance.customerData.MdiParent = Main.Instance;  //Exeption received at this point
                    Main.Instance.customerData.Disposed += new EventHandler(customerData_Disposed);

                    Main.Instance.customerData.Show();


                }

        }
```

But when I try to open a form within the event handler it gives me an InvalidOperationExeption saying: 
"Cross-thread operation not valid: Control 'Main' accessed from a thread other than the thread it was created on."

I tried removing the code line : 
`Main.Instance.customerData.MdiParent = Main.Instance;`
then it works fine. But its necessary also to assign the mdiparent in order to open it as a child form.

Any suggestions to resolve this problem ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the Invoke method on the Main form. You have to pass control over to the Main form to interact with it. The event handler is triggered on a background thread.

Here's some sample code that may work:

```
void serialPort1_DataReceived(object sender, System.IO.Ports.SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
{
    string str = this.serialPort1.ReadLine();
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(str))
    {
        ShowCustomerData(str);
    }   

}

private delegate void ShowCustomerDataDelegate(string s);

private void ShowCustomerData(string s)
{
    if (Main.Instance.InvokeRequired)
    {
        Main.Instance.Invoke(new ShowCustomerDataDelegate(ShowCustomerData), s);
    }
    else
    {

        Main.Instance.customerData = new CustomerData(str);
        Main.Instance.customerData.MdiParent = Main.Instance;  //Exeption received at this point
        Main.Instance.customerData.Disposed += new EventHandler(customerData_Disposed);

        Main.Instance.customerData.Show();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks David.. I will try to learn the Invoke Method. I have never used it.

Answer (score 1):

Your event handler is not running on the UI thread.  To get on the UI thread use the Invoke method of the main form.

Comment: Thanks Richard.. I will try to learn the Invoke Method. I have never used it.

Answer (score 1):

That is simply because a threading commandment in windows is  *"Thou shalt not access UI from any other thread but the UI thread"*

So you need to use [Control.Invoke](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zyzhdc6b.aspx) to run code that Accesses UI on the UI thread.

```
//assuming your within a control and using C# 3 onward..
this.Invoke( () =>
 {
   //anything that UI goes here.
 }
);
```

A little [Stackoverflow Ninja Google Search](http://www.google.com/search?q=cross%20thread%20operation&sitesearch=stackoverflow.com/questions&qscrl=1) Would have helped you out. This happens to be a pretty infamous problem.

This answer seems to be almost exactly your problem:
[Cross-thread operation not valid while listening to a COM port](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1377529/cross-thread-operation-not-valid-while-listening-to-a-com-port)

Comment: Thanks Giddy .. 
Yes I tried googling it, but as I dint knew threading..i tried to get a simpler solutions if exist... but i think i must learn threading and invoke methods :)

Comment: @Niraj There isn't too much too it, any C# book that covers threading will tell you what I've mentioned in the first line (infact thats from an Addison Wesley book =P) Just remember whenever you access UI asynchronously (From another thread) you need to use invoke to switch back to the main UI thread. This applies to WPF and Silverlight too, its called dispatcher there.